# conditional statements through a loop R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
  unique_ref priority_201801 balance_201801 action_201801 priority_201802 balance_201802 action_201802 priority_201803 balance_201803 action_201803
1          1               3             30   text,letter               1             60        letter               2             30          text
2          2               2            -20         visit               1            -40          text               2            -40          call
3          3               3             35        letter               1             35          call               3            -50          text
4          4               0           -100          call               2              0         visit               2            100          call
  priority_201804 balance_201804 action_201804
1              99              0          text
2               0            -20         visit
3               0            -50        letter
4               0           -100          text
```

Above is a sample of my dataset. I want to search through each action looking for the first instance of the action "text", this will then be Week0, I then want to line up the priority's and balances of the next weeks, as Week1, Week2 etc.

Desirable output:

```
  unique_ref week0_priority week0_balance week0_action week1_priority week1_balance week1_action week2_priority week2_balance week2_action
1          1              3            30         text              1            60       letter              2            30         text
2          2              1           -40         text              2           -40         call              0           -20        visit
3          3              3           -50         text              0           -40       letter        No Data       No Data      No Data
4          4              0          -100         text        No Data       No Data      No Data        No Data       No Data      No Data
  week3_priority week3_balance week3_action
1             99             0         text
2        No Data       No Data      No Data
3        No Data       No Data      No Data
4        No Data       No Data      No Data
```

Reproducible example of data:

```
unique_ref=c(1,2,3,4)
priority_201801=c('3','2','3','0')
balance_201801=c('30','-20','35','-100')
action_201801=c('text,letter','visit','letter','call')
priority_201802=c('1','1','1','2')
balance_201802=c('60','-40','35','0')
action_201802=c('letter','text', 'call', 'visit')
priority_201803=c('2','2','3','2')
balance_201803=c('30','-40','-50','100')
action_201803=c('text','call','text','call')
priority_201804=c('99','0','0','0')
balance_201804=c('0','-20','-50','-100')
action_201804=c('text','visit','letter','text')

df3=as.data.frame(cbind(unique_ref,priority_201801,balance_201801,action_201801,priority_201802,balance_201802,action_201802,priority_201803,
                        balance_201803,action_201803,priority_201804,balance_201804,action_201804))
```

Comment: I am not really sure what exactly it is you want to achieve, but perhaps try to put all information inside of the data.frame, since apparently some information is just part of the column names and this is not a proper data structure. I think it would be easiest to add a date column.

Comment: @hannes101 I have the data in this format and I want it as the desirable output. That's why I've asked the question, is there any part of the question that isn't clear at all? Happy to clarify any confusion.

Comment: I am just saying that converting it into long format and after the modifications back to the wide format would probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution involving some reshaping of the data.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dt_long <-     gather(data = df3, key = "unique_ref", value = colnames(df3)[2:13])

colnames(dt_long)[2] <- "Values"
dt3_long <- data.table(dt_long)

dt3_long[, c("Type", "Week.Num") := tstrsplit(unique_ref, "_", fixed = TRUE)]


dt3_merge <-  merge(x = dt3_long
      , y =    unique(dt3_long[like(Values, "text"),.(Type
                                                      ,Values
                                                      , Week.Num


      )])[, .(Week.Num, Week.ID = paste0("week", rank(Week.Num, ties.method = "min" )-1))]

      , by.x = "Week.Num"
      , by.y = "Week.Num"
      , all.x = TRUE
      , allow.cartesian = TRUE
      )
```

The resulting data.table dt3_merge looks like the following and has all necessary information, but just needs to be reshaped.

```
dt3_merge
    Week.Num      unique_ref      Values     Type Week.ID
 1:   201801 priority_201801           3 priority   week0
 2:   201801 priority_201801           2 priority   week0
 3:   201801 priority_201801           3 priority   week0
 4:   201801 priority_201801           0 priority   week0
 5:   201801  balance_201801          30  balance   week0
 6:   201801  balance_201801         -20  balance   week0
 7:   201801  balance_201801          35  balance   week0
 8:   201801  balance_201801        -100  balance   week0
 9:   201801   action_201801 text,letter   action   week0
10:   201801   action_201801       visit   action   week0
11:   201801   action_201801      letter   action   week0
12:   201801   action_201801        call   action   week0
13:   201802 priority_201802           1 priority   week1
14:   201802 priority_201802           1 priority   week1
15:   201802 priority_201802           1 priority   week1
16:   201802 priority_201802           2 priority   week1
17:   201802  balance_201802          60  balance   week1
18:   201802  balance_201802         -40  balance   week1
19:   201802  balance_201802          35  balance   week1
20:   201802  balance_201802           0  balance   week1
21:   201802   action_201802      letter   action   week1
22:   201802   action_201802        text   action   week1
23:   201802   action_201802        call   action   week1
24:   201802   action_201802       visit   action   week1
25:   201803 priority_201803           2 priority   week2
26:   201803 priority_201803           2 priority   week2
27:   201803 priority_201803           3 priority   week2
28:   201803 priority_201803           2 priority   week2
29:   201803  balance_201803          30  balance   week2
30:   201803  balance_201803         -40  balance   week2
31:   201803  balance_201803         -50  balance   week2
32:   201803  balance_201803         100  balance   week2
33:   201803   action_201803        text   action   week2
34:   201803   action_201803        call   action   week2
35:   201803   action_201803        text   action   week2
36:   201803   action_201803        call   action   week2
37:   201804 priority_201804          99 priority   week3
38:   201804 priority_201804           0 priority   week3
39:   201804 priority_201804           0 priority   week3
40:   201804 priority_201804           0 priority   week3
41:   201804  balance_201804           0  balance   week3
42:   201804  balance_201804         -20  balance   week3
43:   201804  balance_201804         -50  balance   week3
44:   201804  balance_201804        -100  balance   week3
45:   201804   action_201804        text   action   week3
46:   201804   action_201804       visit   action   week3
47:   201804   action_201804      letter   action   week3
48:   201804   action_201804        text   action   week3
    Week.Num      unique_ref      Values     Type Week.ID
```

Finally the call to dcast to reshape it into wide

```
dt3_merge[, `:=`(id = 1:.N), by = list(unique_ref)]
dt3_result <- dcast(dt3_merge, id ~ Type + Week.ID, value.var=c('Values'))


     id action_week0 action_week1 action_week2 action_week3 balance_week0 balance_week1
1:  1  text,letter       letter         text         text            30            60
2:  2        visit         text         call        visit           -20           -40
3:  3       letter         call         text       letter            35            35
4:  4         call        visit         call         text          -100             0
   balance_week2 balance_week3 priority_week0 priority_week1 priority_week2 priority_week3
1:            30             0              3              1              2             99
2:           -40           -20              2              1              2              0
3:           -50           -50              3              1              3              0
4:           100          -100              0              2              2              0
```